# how to create and deploy contract in bigchaindb directly or with using any api?

Tags: blockchain, bigchaindb

i want to deploy a contract on bigchaindb . How to do it?
If it works with eris then how to configure eris with bigchaindb and deploy a contract?

Answer (score 0):

Currently BigchainDB v.1.0.0 does not support Smart Contracts.  But you can use crypto conditions to allow some logic before transfer assets.  For more information check  [official documentation](https://docs.bigchaindb.com/en/latest/smart-contracts.html)